# Find the set of all positive integers n for which there is a real matrix $A$ of dimension $n×n$ such that Inverse matrix of $A^{-1}=-A$.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

> Find the set of all positive integers n for which there is a real matrix $A$ of dimension $n \times n$ such that $A^{-1}=-A .$

So,I tried the problem in this way that as $A^{-1}=-A$, so; it implies $A^{2}=-I$ .If $\lambda $ be one eigenvalue of $A$ then $\lambda^{2}=-1,$So, $\lambda=\pm i$,where $i$ is the imaginary unit.So,for $n=1, A$ is a scalar quantity, if $A=a^{1\times1}$ then $a^{2}=-1\Rightarrow a=\pm i.$ But it is said that A is a real matrix, so, if $a=\pm i$ then A can not be a real matrix.So,$n=1$ is not a possible integer.For $n=2$ eigen values are $\pm i$for $n=3$ there is one eigenvalue is zero and other two are $\pm i$. So, for all odd integer $n$ there will be one eigenvalue zero and other eigenvalues are $\pm i$ and for even integer $n$ there will be even number of eigenvalues are zero and other eigenvalues are $\pm i$ or all eigenvalues are $\pm i$ or all eigenvalues are zero.

For a real symmetric matrix all eigenvalues are real numbers and for a real skew-symmetric matrix all eigenvalues are either zero or complex numbers.

Is this thought correct or please give some idea or give some proof.

Comment: Have you considered $$\begin{bmatrix}0&1\\-1&0\end{bmatrix}?$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$A^2=-I$$

We have $\det(A)^2 = (-1)^n$, hence $n$ must be even.

Now, let $B=\begin{bmatrix} 0 & 1 \\ -1 & 0\end{bmatrix}$, then we have $B^2=-I_2$.

Consider $diag(B, B, \ldots, B) \in \mathbb{R}^{2n}$ in general.

Comment: Why n must be even?

Comment: what is $(-1)^n$ when $n$ is odd? what about when $n$ is even?

Comment: when n will odd $(-1)^{n}=-1$ and when n will even then $(-1)^{n}=1$.

Comment: Actually for $n$ odd $det(A^{2})=-1$ but it imply that eigen values will be zero or $\pm i $. So, how can we say that for n odd we can not get any matrix such that $A^{2}=-A$ ?

Comment: I understand what you want to say. $det(A^{2})=(-1)^{n}$ means for n is odd integer we will get $det(A^{2})=-1$ but it implies $det(A)$ will be$ \pm i$ ,which can not be possible. Actually I am thinking in the sense of eigen values.Now the answer is clear to me.